# Non-printable control characters over serial port in C++ using WriteFile

Tags: c++, serial-port, control-characters

I am trying to write a control character (<kbd>CTRL-T</kbd>, which is `#20` in ASCII table) to the serial port using the `WriteFile()` function, but apparently it does not work.

When I use putty and press <kbd>CTRL+T</kbd>, I receive a response over the serial port for communication with an ATI force sensor I work with. Below is a snapshot:

[image: Putty Terminal]

However, when I use the `WriteFile()` function in C++, I get no response from the sensor, which indicates to me that the <kbd>CTRL-T</kbd> command is not written to the serial port. Below is the code snippet:

```
// set write character to CTRL-T (#20 = 0x14) 
char t = 0x14;
// write the character to the serial port
m_serialPort.Write(&t,1);
// read 14 bytes with 1000 ms timeout from the serial port
m_serialPort.Read_N(str_read,14,1000);
```

I have tested the functions `Write` and `Read_N`, and they work fine when I deal with printable characters.

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

EDIT: Here is a sample code:

```
// SerialTest.cpp : main project file.

#include "stdafx.h"
#include"SerialCommHelper.h"
#include <windows.h>  
#include <iostream>
using namespace System;

CSerialCommHelper m_serialPort;

int main()
{
    std::string comPort = "COM1";
    std::string str_read;
    // Open the serial Port
    m_serialPort.Init(comPort,9600,0,1,8);
    m_serialPort.Start();
    m_serialPort.Purge();

    // set write character to CTRL-T (#20 = 0x14) 
    char t = 0x14;
    // write the character to the serial port
    m_serialPort.Write(&t,1);
    // read 14 bytes with 1000 ms timeout from the serial port
    m_serialPort.Read_N(str_read,14,1000);
    std::cout << str_read;
    system("pause");
    m_serialPort.Stop();
    m_serialPort.UnInit();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a minimal complete example, which shows the declaration of m_serialPort?

Comment: I am using this https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2682/Serial-Communication-in-Windows for serial communication in C++ and I have declared m_serialPort as:

CSerialCommHelper m_serialPort;

Comment: I added the full code in EDIT

Comment: What makes you think `CTRL-T` is ASCII #20? Have you tried actually sniffing the COM port to see what Putty *actually* sends when you type `CTRL-T`?

Comment: Pretty typical about codeproject.com projects, they only ever work by accident.  As always it quits where the going gets tough, it completely skips the need to setup the handshaking for the port.  You will not receive anything went it is set wrong.  Throw it away, use the api and initialize the DCB yourself.  Gazillions of google hits show you how to do that.